# K&R histogram of length of words

Tags: c

I am doing exercise 1-13 of K&R. The problem is to print a histogram of the lengths of words in the input. This is the easier problem, printing the histogram with horizontal bars. This is what I came up with. Is there a better way to do this? Are there any bugs?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLEN 10

int main(){
    int c,length;
    int hist[MAXLEN+1];

    length=0;
    for(int i=0;i<MAXLEN+1;i++) hist[i]=0;

    while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
        if((c==' ' || c=='\t' || c=='\n') && length){
            if(length>MAXLEN)
                hist[MAXLEN]++;
            else
                hist[length-1]++;
            length=0;
        }
        else if(c!=' ' && c!='\t' && c!='\n')
            length++;
    }
    //to deal with situations in which input doesn't end in a space or newline or tab
    if(length>MAXLEN)
        hist[MAXLEN]++;
    else if(length)
        hist[length-1]++;

    //printing the histogram horizontally
    putchar('\n');
    for(int i=0;i<MAXLEN;i++){
        printf("%3d|",i+1);
        for(int j=0;j<hist[i];j++) putchar('x');
        putchar('\n');
    }
    printf(">%d|",MAXLEN);
    for(int i=0;i<hist[MAXLEN];i++) putchar('x');
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Declare and initialize variables in one go

You can initialize a value at the same time you declare it. This even works for `struct`s and arrays. For example:

```
int main() {   
    int c = 0;
    int length = 0;
    int hist[MAXLEN+1] = {0}; // Initializes all elements to 0

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ...
```

## Use `isspace()`

Instead of manually checking against spaces, tabs and newlines, use [`isspace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) from `<ctype.h>`.

## Split your code into multiple functions

Even for a simple program like this, it is a good exercise to split the code into multiple functions, and reduce the responsibility of each function as much as possible. This way for example, `main()` could be reduced to:

```
int main() {
    int hist[MAXLEN + 1] = {0};

    build_histogram(hist, MAXLEN);
    print_histogram(hist, MAXLEN);
}
```

Then `build_histogram()` could be written like this:

```
static void build_histogram(int hist[], size_t hist_size) {
    int c;
    int length = 0;

    while ((c=getchar())!=EOF) {
        if (isspace(c)) {
            add_word(hist, hist_size, length);
            length = 0;
        } else {
            length++;
        }
    }

    add_word(hist, hist_size, length);
}
```

So its main function is to scan for words. Then `add_word()` does the actual work of recording the length of a word in the histogram:

```
static void add_word(int hist[], size_t hist_size, size_t length) {
    if (length > hist_size)
        hist[hist_size]++;
    else if (length)
        hist[length - 1]++;
}
```

You can use a similar approach for `print_histogram()`.

Comment: I would like to use all of these and i know functions too but at this point of the book those features haven't been taught

Comment: I noticed you wrote `for (int i=0; ...)`, that is not K&R C, but C99. Are you sure you are only using features taught by the book, and does that even matter in the long run?

Comment: No it doesn't matter. But i am just trying follow along with the book. and i am realizing that it doesn't matter in this example, more so, bcz encapsulating the code into functions isn't providing any extra functionality to me so it is valid.

Comment: @aritra Encapsulating the code into functions may not provide any value to _you_. That's ok since you are in a unique position, as you are the author of this code. Everyone else isn't, and splitting the code into functions is a benefit for these readers. When they read such a function they can quickly see what the function is supposed to do and can guess whether it really does that. This is much more difficult if a large function consists entirely of fine-grained variable assignments that repeat over and over.